# Altium Designer (23.8.1) two layers visible in 3D view mode

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

I think the picture explains my problem best:

[image]

My solder Mask color is green, I set it's transperency to 0% for this screenshot.
However, there is some blue "overlay" on the top and the bottom of my PCB, it is only visible in 3D view and in Board planning mode. It's edges are also not rounded, like the ones of the PCB.
From what I could gather via the board planning mode I think these are Top Solder (Board Layer Stack) and Bottom Solder (Board Layer Stack) layers.

The annoying thing is, that every time I change the view angle The colors change because the Solder Mask and this blue layer are on the same height, so at some angles the board might be completely blue, at some completely green.
I think this happened after I made this PCB to a 4 Layer PCB and then decrease it's overall size.

Here are some more pictures:

Different rotation

[image]

Board planning mode (Active Layer: Multi-Layer)

[image]

Comment: If you have bought altium (aka not pirated version), you should obviously ask/raise a ticket on the company for that issue

Comment: I have a student's license, I tried to ask but they do not have support for the student's license.

Comment: When viewing in 3D is there a side panel showing what colors are assigned to different design layers? Please share that so we can see which layers are associated with the blue color.

Comment: It is none of the colors that I can edit in the 3D view. If I switch to the "By Layer" view in the 3D settings it does not show anymore. Also in my Gerber Files it does not show luckily.
The layer Colors does not correspond with the colors in the 3D View, there is a seperate option for that.